# Android Json Parse

Tags: android, java

Всем привет. Через Android-query получаю JSONObject json по http ссылке.

Получаемый пример json:

```
{"code":200,"message":null,"response":[{"id":"6","testid":"3","title":"Тест 1"},{"id":"7","testid":"3","title":"Тест 15"},{"id":"10","testid":"3","title":"Тест 55"}]}
```

Нужно распарсить "response", для возможности получить строчку по i (не по id). 
Нужно выводить строчки в зависимости от i. Сначала выводится response[0], после response[1]...
Хотелось бы что-то вроде (для примера): response[0].title - выведет текст названия первого элемента и т.д.
Как реализовать это на java?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ http://habrahabr.ru/company/naumen/blog/228279/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String jsonFromUrl = "{\"code\":200,\"message\":null,\"response\":[{\"id\":\"6\",\"testid\":\"3\",\"title\":\"Тест 1\"},{\"id\":\"7\",\"testid\":\"3\",\"title\":\"Тест 15\"},{\"id\":\"10\",\"testid\":\"3\",\"title\":\"Тест 55\"}]}";
JSONObject object = null;
try {
    object = new JSONObject(jsonFromUrl);
    JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("response");
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
        JSONObject objInArray = array.getJSONObject(i);
        //делаем что хотим с объектом из массива под номером i
        String title = objInArray.getString("title");
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 Iterator<String> iter = json.keys();   
 while (iter.hasNext()) {

    String key = iter.next();
    try {
        Object value = json.get(key);
    } catch (JSONException e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Совершенно не то, что надо. У @Nick есть массив response, который надо вывести "по порядку".